# AJAX only update when changes in the database - Codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to only update the page when their are updates in the database but i am unsure how to do that.

I was thinking of comparing ids stored into the database because each ID is unique so if i make some sort of expression that compares the current array stored or picked up by AJAX to the ids in the database. But i am unsure how to compare ids and check if their is a new update

Any help would be appreciated

Controller

```
public function insertJSON()
    {
        $this->load->model("values");
        $queryresults = $this->values->getDb();

        $id = array();
        $arr = array();
        $arr2 = array();


        foreach($queryresults as $row)
        {
            $id[] = $row->id;
            $arr[] =  $row->post;
            $arr2[] = $row->img;
        }

            $data = array();
            $data[] = $id
            $data[] = $arr;
            $data[] = $arr2;

            echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

View

```
 <script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>
      $('#getdata').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
          url: '<?php echo base_url().'index.php/welcome/insertJSON';?>',
          async: false,
          type: "POST",
          success: function(data) {

            // thought i could do something like
                   if(data.change in database) do bla bla

            var id = data[0];
            var arr = data[1];
            var arr2 = data[2]

          }
        })
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: you should take a look into event driven server side frameworks like socket.io - http://www.socket.io

Comment: You might also consider using websockets

Comment: also it strictly depend uo on your situation, If you have large traffic then consider `websockets`. Also you can use a normal polling techniques to make this work.

Comment: A quick solution would be to save the most recent `data` response to a var outside of the success function callback. Then, compare it to the current response -- if they're different, make your updates. I haven't researched it enough to say if this is the best method, so I'll leave it as a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a simple way to do this.
create a session variable and assign it the last id. than on the page take this session id on a hidden input.
Now when you are sending ajax request you can take hidden input's value and send it to controller function where you can query for last id. If last id from query is not equal to session id you should echo other wise echo 0. in ajax request check if response is coming from controller and it is greater than 0 change the page with new id. Than update the session id with ajax